# YUV420 to grayscale in C++

Tags: c++, yuv, v4l2

I'm trying to write a function to convert a camera stream with a YUV420 pixel format to grayscale. To my understanding, I only need to extract the Y values since these are the luminance of the image frames.

I am using this page as a reference https://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/uapi/v4l/pixfmt-yuv420.html, but I am having trouble understanding what a planar format is and how to essentially skip through the UV values. I think I would need to get the 2x2 Y values (e.g., Y00, Y01, Y10, Y11 in the above link) for every UV values, but I'm also not sure if I should just write them consecutively into my image frame's destination. That is, if I have a pointer to my destination and I have these for Y values, should I just write them in the order of Y00, Y01, Y10, Y11, Y02, etc?

Comment: Planar means all the Y pixels for the whole frame are stored first, then all the U values for the whole frame, then all the V values. By contrast, in a packed format you would have the YUV values packed together for the first pixel, then all the YUV values for the second pixel etc.

Comment: Basically you would take a whole WxH frame of consecutive Y values, then skip over half that many UV values before starting the next frame.

Comment: There's a nice diagram here http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/recipes2.html. Look at `Position in byte stream` to see how all the Y values arrive first.

Comment: Oh I see! So I would just need to run through each cell of the Ys, and then putting them into the destination would essentially be all the Y planes on top of each other?

Comment: Did you solve this or do you need additional help?